# svelte prop value not working with if statement

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit, svelte-component

this is my svelte component code

```
<script>
    export let canCascade = true;
    let show = true;

    function cascade() {
        if (canCascade) {
            show = !show;
        }
    }
</script>

{#if show}
<div class="shade" on:click|self={cascade}>
    shade
</div>
{/if}
```

When I use the component as `<Component canCascade=false />` the 'if block' doesn't work.
But hard-coding the value inside just works fine.
Am I missing something here - some conceptual error?

Comment: try `<Component canCascade={false} />`

Comment: Without parenthesis it's passed as a string, not a boolean https://svelte.dev/repl/a5c6c7a3468f4f5d86336c571cc281b4?version=3.46.4

Answer (score 1):

Like @Corrl pointed out in the comments, you need to use {brackets}. If you don't, the variable will follow the rules of an html attribute.

Working repl https://svelte.dev/repl/d13df678eab243e9a13fb705da197219?version=3

Answer (score 1):

In Svelte when we want to pass JavaScript value / expression to an attribute of a component we **need to wrap the value / expression with curly brackets {}**.

**Otherwise, it will be used as a string**.

As an example, take a look at the following code:

***Component.svelte:***

```
<script>
  export let test = true;

  $test: console.log(`typeof test = ${typeof test}`);
</script>
```

***App.svelte:***

```
<script>
  import Component from "./Component.svelte";
</script>

<Component test=true />
<div />
```

When you will open the console inside the browser developer tools,
**the output will be**:

> ***typeof test = string***